# Nested Gridview RowCommand event cause Parent GridView RowCommand fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I have two gridview , one is parent and another is child , each gridview has its own OnRowCommand event. when a gridview rowcommand fire for a child row , rowcommand event of parent fired. and this cause  following error in gvProject row command error (when we have few projects and many folder)

> error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

how can I solve this? this is my gridView :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProject" runat="server" SkinID="ExpandableGrid" DataSourceID="odsProject" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="gvProject_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvProject_RowCommand">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <i class="btnCollapseExpand icon contrast-color collapse icon-ellipsis-h fright" onclick="ExpandCollapseGridView(this);" style="cursor: pointer"></i>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles, Select %>">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chbSelect" runat="server" TabIndex="9" CssClass="contrast-checkbox" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="center" />
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="center" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles,Code %>" DataField="Code" SortExpression="Code"></asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles,Name %>" DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-4" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles, Customer %>" DataField="Customer" SortExpression="Customer.Name">
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-4" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles,ProgressStatus %>" DataField="ProjectStatus" SortExpression="ProjectStatus.Name">
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles, ActivityStatus%>" SortExpression="Status">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#System.Convert.ToString(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Status") ) ? Resources.Titles.Enable : Resources.Titles.Disable) %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles, Edit %>">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <a id="IbtnEdit" tabindex="11" href="ProjectDetail.aspx?Edit=<%# Eval("ID").ToString() %>" class="btnIcon hasTooltip" title="<%= Resources.Titles.EditProject %>"><i class="icon icon-edit"></i></a>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="center" />
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="center" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles, Delete %>">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDeleteProject" TabIndex="12" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteProject" title="<%$ Resources:Titles,DeleteProject %>" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>' CssClass="btnIcon hasTooltip">
                                                 <i class="icon icon-trash-o"></i>
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="center" />
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="center" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles, AddFolder %>">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAddFolder" TabIndex="13" runat="server" CommandName="AddFolder" title="<%$ Resources:Titles,AddFolder %>" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>' CssClass="btnIcon hasTooltip">
                                                 <i class="icon icomoon-icon-AddFolder"></i>
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle Width="5%" CssClass="center" />
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="center" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <tr class="collapsible_panel" height="50px" id="detailRow<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>">
                                                <td colspan="100%">
                                                    <div class="collapsible_panel_content">
                                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvFolders" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowCommand="gvFolders_RowCommand">
                                                            <Columns>
                                                                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles,FolderName %>" DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" />
                                                                </asp:BoundField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles,FolderCode %>">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <%#System.Convert.ToString(Eval("Code").ToString().Trim())%>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" />
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles,Creator %>">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <%#System.Convert.ToString(GetUser(Eval("OwnerID")))%>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" />
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles, Edit %>">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEditFolder" TabIndex="7" runat="server" CommandName="EditFolder" title="<%$ Resources:Titles,EditFolder %>" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>' CssClass="btnIcon hasTooltip">
                                                                            <i class="icon icon-edit"></i>
                                                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="center col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1" />
                                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="center" />
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Titles, Delete %>">
                                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDeleteFolder" TabIndex="7" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteFolder" title="<%$ Resources:Titles,DeleteFolder %>" CommandArgument='<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>' CssClass="btnIcon hasTooltip">
                                                                            <i class="icon icon-trash-o"></i>
                                                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="center col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1" />
                                                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="center" />
                                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                            </Columns>
                                                        </asp:GridView>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="noPadding" />
                                        <ItemStyle Width="0px" CssClass="noPadding" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <%= Resources.Messages.NoProjectIsForView %>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

and this is my rowcommand events :

```
    protected void gvProject_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex, id;

    rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridView grid = (GridView)sender;

    if (grid.ID == "gvProject")
    {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(grid.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "DeleteProject":

                ClearForm();
                hfID.Value = id.ToString();
                HiddenField1.Value = id.ToString();

                lblDeleteMessage.Text = string.Empty;

                Global.ShowModalBox(upProjectDelete, "delete_modal");

                break;

            case "AddFolder":

                ClearForm();
                hfID.Value = id.ToString();

                Global.ShowModalBox(upAddFolder, "AddFolderModal");

                break;
        }
    }
}

protected void gvFolders_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex, id;

    rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridView grid = (GridView)sender;

    id = Convert.ToInt32(grid.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);

    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "EditFolder":

            if (grid.ID == "gvFolders")
            {
                ClearForm();
                hfID.Value = id.ToString();

                Folder folder = Providers.Folder.GetById(id);
                txtFolderName.Text = folder.Name;

                EditType = eEditType.Edit;
                lblBoxTitle.Text = Resources.Titles.EditFolder;

                Global.ShowModalBox(upAddFolder, "AddFolderModal");
            }

            break;

        case "DeleteFolder":

            if (grid.ID == "gvFolders")
            {
                ClearForm();
                hfID.Value = id.ToString();

                lblDeleteFolderMessage.Text = string.Empty;

                Global.ShowModalBox(upAddFolder, "DeleteFolderModal");
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that only way to solve this problem is to check command name in gvproject rowcommand event :

```
protected void gvProject_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
    int rowIndex, id;

    rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridView grid = (GridView)sender;

    if (e.CommandName == "DeleteProject" || e.CommandName == "AddFolder")
    {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(grid.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);

        ...    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a stable solution because it's based on the assumption that commandName are different for each GridView.

Comment: @PaoloCosta : Yes ,I see , grid.Rows[rowIndex] does not contain a Property with name : Value

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake, I cleared the first part of the answer. I currently don't know the origin of the error....

Comment: @PaoloCosta : thank you for answer, No problem still exist , gvFolders RowCommand event does not have any problem ,  gvproject RowCommand event has problem.

Comment: I just realized the sender is always gvProject even if you click in an inner linkButton, so the only solution is really to check the CommandName value in the RowCommand event handler. I'll delete my answer as it doesn't make sense.